# Cómo hago que aparezcan los manejadores del input number

Tags: next.js, tailwind

Estoy usando react, next js, tailwind. Al colocar el input, solo se muestran los manejadores cuando paso el cursor o doy clic.

```
    <input
         type="number"
         className="w-20 text-2xl mr-8"
    />
```